# Filtering rows based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

So i have two dataframes, one is:

```
ID         Player        Strength

1003       Karl             20
1004       Karl             40
1005       Karl             50
1006       Karl             50
1007       Jen              17
1008       Jen              60
1009       Void             200
1010       Void             100
1011       Void             200
1012       Fin              90
```

and the other contains the maximum strength of each player

```
Player        Max Strength

Karl              50
Jen               60
Void             200
Fin               90
```

What I want to do is **filter the first dataframe** to only preserve the rows where the Strength value is equivalent to Max Strength in the second dataframe. Hence the resulting dataframe would be:

```
ID          Player          Strength

1005         Karl               50
1006         Karl               50
1008         Jen                60
1009         Void              200
1011         Void              200
1012         Fin                90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df1 %>%
 filter(Strength == df2$Max_Strength[match(Player, df2$Player)])

    ID Player Strength
1 1005   Karl       50
2 1006   Karl       50
3 1008    Jen       60
4 1009   Void      200
5 1011   Void      200
6 1012    Fin       90
```

And the same idea with `base R`:

```
df1[with(df2, Max_Strength[match(df1$Player, Player)]) == df1$Strength, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `semi_join`:

```
main_df %>% 
    semi_join(second_frame, by = c("Player", "Strength")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dplyr option:

```
df1 %>%
left_join(df2,by = "Player") %>%
filter(Strengh==Max_Strength)
```